# Quickly turn screen lock off and on on Android 7

Tags: settings, lock-screens, 7.1-nougat, quick-settings

Often there are situations where I access my phone frequently (every few minutes) and I don't need the screen lock. Always going to *settings → security → screen lock* to change the settings is very annyoing, so I'm looking for an easy option to quickly turn the screen lock on and off or change between the screen lock options (none/swipe/pattern, PIN, password).

Ideal would be an icon in the status bar like the WiFi on/off.
Is this possible on Android 7 (I'm using Lineage OS).

Unlocking via fingerprint is not an option.

Comment: Does Smart Lock not fit your needs?

Comment: The option which I have with Lineage OS 14.1 is to define different system profiles. I can create a system profile where I set "Lock screen mode" to "Disable lock screen" and another one with "System default", where the default setting then must be set to e.g. PIN or pattern. Then I can change between these profiles by placing the "System profiles" icon to the status bar.
This is not bad, but I'd prefere a simple button to change between the lock screen settings.